# What's the max temperature a MBP battery can get to?

Tags: macbook-pro, battery

What's the max temperature a MBP battery can get to when user is using it?

*Question is clear. If you have an answer, share the answer assuming you wan't to share it. **If you don't have an answer, stop asking for clarifications!** I can't make this question more clear if even you sacrificed your firstborn for me.*

Comment: Repeating the question within the question post does not really help. Which problem are you trying to solve here?

Comment: What's the max temperature a MBP battery can get to? I'm trying to learn the answer to this question. Question is extremely clear. Why do you think its not clear?

Comment: What will you do with the answer, with which problem will it help you? What difference does it make whether the answer is 60 ℃ or 90 ℃? Is this "can" as "is allowed to get before it gets damaged" or "can" as "has been measured in practical use"? (also see bmike's answer below for more details about why the question is far from clear).

Comment: What's the maximum temperature my battery can get to while I'm using my battery? I'm a regular user doing regular things like watching 4k vids or coding stuff on the mac. This is the question. Are you able to understand what I'm saying?

Comment: The battery shouldn't get warm when being used, it only warms while being charged.

Answer (score 1):

Batteries get hot when they charge, so in heavy system usage / discharge, they do not generate any heat. Are you confusing thermal throttling to protect the battery from conducted heat and slow / paused charging with high CPU temperatures that will affect useful work output? Since they absorb heat from other components, those other sensor trigger thermal controls and system shutdown in my experience.

Comment: What's the max temperature a MBP battery can get to? Is it difficult to read this?

Comment: There is no max limit on high temperature like there is at absolute zero @HABALABALUCOMINGFORTHEBOOTY insulting people when you’re not clear tends to backfire here. I’ve edited my answer in hopes you can make use of my experience. If not, no worries - just try to stay cooler than your CPU and you should be fine.

Comment: @HABALABALUCOMINGFORTHEBOOTY The [What topics can I ask about here? page](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) says this stack is for " ...question[s] about a practical problem you are trying to solve..." Your question about temperature is a technical question, but it does not appear to be address a "practical problem you are trying to solve." Are you trying to solve a practical problem? If so, what is the problem?